# Cannot find name 'PDFDocumentProxy'.ts(2304) when using pdfjs

Tags: typescript, pdf.js

When I use pdfjs's type `PDFDocumentProxy` in the typescript project, shows error:

```
Cannot find name 'PDFDocumentProxy'.ts(2304)
```

I have already checked the project `package.json` and make sure I am imported the `PDFDocumentProxy`:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/pdfjs-dist": "^2.10.378",
    "@types/redux-logger": "^3.0.9"
  }
```

why still shows this error? what should I do to fixed this issue? I am using the `PDFDocumentProxy` type like this:

```
const [currentPdf, setCurrentPdf] = useState<PDFDocumentProxy>();
```

I have already tried import like this:

```
import type {PDFDocumentProxy, PDFPageProxy} from 'pdfjs-dist/types/display/api';
```